# Sum of Gauss Quadrature Weights

Tags: numerical-methods

The sum of weights for Gaussian quadrature depends on the dimension of the interval.
For example, the sum of the weights over the interval [-1, 1] is 2.

My question is simply why?

Answer (score 1):

A simple explanation to this would be to think geometrically. Gaussian Quadrature converts the integral to a sum over the domain of the integrand evaluated at specific quadrature points multiplied  by a weighting function. Think of the weighting function as the width of the interval whose area is represented by the height of f(xi). You are essentially adding the areas of a number of rectangular strips.

As a result, the sum of the widths will always equal our domain size for the integral, in this case 2.

Comment: Thank you.
Is there an analytical explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is just a specific case of the general case:

By def of gaussian quadrature

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} w_i f(x_i)$

Suppose we take 
$f(x)=1$

Then we end up with $\sum_{n=1}^{N} w_i = b-a $

In your case, on the interval [-1,1] we see that the sum of the weights would indeed be 2.

Comment: Basically, recall how the quadrature rule was derived: "find the nodes and weights that exactly integrate polynomials of up to degree $2n-1$". The *constant* function $1$ is among those polynomials to be exactly integrated.